# Different fast days

Tags: minhag, fast-days

I'm looking for a list of ALL of the fast days observed by certain Jews and why.

What are some fast days observed by certain groups of Jews. As an example, some Jews have the custom of fasting the Friday before Parshas Chukas.

What are some other days?

Comment: See ShA OC 580.

Comment: By stating "certain" Jews, can we infer that the answer should exclude the common fast days that SHOULD be observed by ALL Jews, such as Yom Kippur, Tisha B'Av, Ta'anit Esther, etc.? Also "certain" Jews, namely first borns only fast on Erev Pesach, unless they attend a siyum. Should we include similar fast days to that one?